# How to Use a Barcode Scanner with .Net 5.0

Tags: winforms, barcode-scanner, .net-5

I want to develop an app that utilises a barcode scanner ( of various types ) .

I don't want to use the barcode scanner like a keyboard ( intercepting keystrokes etc )

Is there a .net 5 library or part of the framework that I can use in a winfoms app?

Comment: how about [ZXing.Net](https://github.com/micjahn/ZXing.Net)

Comment: If you can tolerate Middleware/Library becoming Windows-dependent(= only works on Windows), you may be able to use POS for.NET or OPOS. If not, you will need to control the device directly using the serial port. In that case, you need to support the command/response/notification format specific to each scanner.

Comment: I wrote an app like this (sorta, in this case it's various Windows CE devices with built-in scanner and I got sick of putting vendor specific library). In the end it's just an amalgam of each vendor specific protocol, so if there's a new vendor with different protocol, I'd have to manually add the support. Using a middleware like @kunif said is a much better approach.

Comment: the vender's library should be best fit the hardware. to minimize effort to adapt different venders, you can make some dependency injection, and you business logic only to depend on some `IScanner` interface.